# Entity Framework can't connect to my database

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework-core, blazor

I'm trying to connect to an empty SQL Server database I've created in SSMS for a Blazor project I'm working on. As part of this, I'm trying to create a new table, but when I try to migrate it to my database, I can't seem to get it to work.

When I attempt to update the database in the console, the `update-database` command seems to work fine, but nothing is actually pushed to my database. If I take the connection string out of my `.json` file and pass it directly to `options.UseSqlServer()`, this error is raised when trying to update the database:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SNI_PN11, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Remote connections are enabled, and the connection string is just directly copied from my SQL Server explorer. Only thing I can think of is maybe an incompatibility with my connection string properties or something?

My connection string is:

```
Data Source = Desktop-UGF6TEE\\MyDataSource; Integrated Security = True; Connect Timeout = 30; Encrypt = False; Trust Server Certificate = False; Application Intent = ReadWrite; Multi Subnet Failover = False
```

Comment: make sure sql server service is runiing from services in windwos. Also Replace MyDataSource with (.)if you are connecting locally.

Comment: In my services, I See MSSQLServer and MSSQL$MyDataSource, so I believe the services are running. Have also amended the connection string on my original post, but it still doesn't seem to be working

Comment: try Integrated Security=SSPI;

Comment: This seemed to work, thankyou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try Integrated Security=SSPI;

I think the issue comes here.